# database synchronization for iOS with its web server

Tags: objective-c, ios

How to maintain a sync of database between my iPhone app and web server, If there is a update on the web server database there should be a update alert on my app. is that possible please help me on this, help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks 
Deepesh

Comment: Could you provide more details ? Is your webserver exposing the data using an API ? Is it RESTFull ? etc.

Comment: Hi martin, I have a mysql database which has a basic structure but the db has big files stored in it in html format, I can write apis, but i don't won't the hassle of maintaining apis, is there a way to download the entire database whenever there is a change in the content,

Comment: You can also have a look at http://parse.com/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to register push notifications if you want the user to receive update alerts when the app is not open. Then the data can be synced to their device once they open the app.

For maintaining a synchronized set of data you might want to look into using a framework such as [RestKit](http://restkit.org/) which provides an object mapping system that allows you to synchronize Core Data with a remote object store. [Here is their object mapping doc](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/Docs/Object%20Mapping.md).